# Change the log format layout for Cordapp

Tags: kotlin, logstash, corda

It looks like cordapp outputs console log in log4j format layout. I need to have it in logstash json layout.  I have already implemented a library that outputs in logstash json layout and this library works well with spring boot or regular application. However when used it with Cordapp, the cordapp log4j layout always overrides.

**Details on how I am trying to implement this:**

I have extended `log4j..ConfigurationFactory` to create a `CustomConfigurationFactory`.  The main purpose of the `CustomConfigurationFactory` is to implement Logstash layout and custom rolling of the the log file. There is few more meta data that is included with every log statement. It uses the `org.slf4j.Logger` in the the background along with the custom configuration to log statements in the custom format and implement our custom rolling.  This is created as an independent library so it can be used across all our application.

I am using this custom logging library for logging purpose. It works for the accompanying Spring boot application that interacts with the Corda nodes however the logging on the Corda node itself is in the default log4j format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you editing the log4j file in the /config folder of the cordapp, right? (like in this example https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Tokens/bikemarket/config/[dev|test])

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you have tried out. What changes did you made etc. so that we can suggest you better.

Answer (score 0):

Corda uses log4j for logging, you could provide your custom format in the log4j configuration files. You could find more details on logging here in Corda documentation: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/node-administration.html#logging